# Make GUI move with window

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to set up a GUI that moves along with a window of a software that I'm using. My general goal is to block a certain area of that software to be clickable. I've implemented a very simple solution that achieves this for a static window, however it's not anywhere near an optimal solution because whenever I resize/move the software, the blocked part becomes misaligned.

```html
#Persistent
Gui, +alwaysontop -caption
Gui, show, w238 h30 x1032 y30
Gui, 1:Color, 545454

Gui, 2:+alwaysontop -caption
Gui, 2:show, w238 h30 x2008 y30
Gui, 2:Color, 545454

Gui, 3:+alwaysontop -caption
Gui, 3:show, w238 h30 x1032 y732
Gui, 3:Color, 545454

Gui, 4:+alwaysontop -caption
Gui, 4:show, w238 h30 x2008 y732
Gui, 4:Color, 545454

Gui, 5:+alwaysontop -caption
Gui, 5:show, w46 h36 x3676 y33
Gui, 5:Color, 545454

return
```

My 2nd attempt looks like this:

```html
Win_Hwnd := WinExist("ahk_exe excel.exe ahk_class XLMAIN")

; Gui Create
Gui, Color, yellow
Gui, Font, s12 cRed, Bold Verdana
Gui, Add, Text,, This is Text
Gui, +LastFound +ToolWindow +AlwaysOnTop -Caption -Border HWNDGui_Hwnd
DllCall("SetParent", "uint", Gui_Hwnd, "uint", Win_Hwnd)
Gui, Show, w238 h30 x1 y1 ; Position on Gui Parent
return

Esc::ExitApp
```

This piece of code works perfectly with Excel, Word, Notepad, however not with the specific software (PokerStars) that I'm using. I've replaced the ahk_exe and ahk_class according to the logic of the code and using Window Spy to identify the parameters, however when running the desired software, the gui only appears in a fixed position according to the x/y coordinates.

My question:
Why does this code work for some software, but not for others?
Is there any other approach I could be using to achieve the desired result?

Edit:

I have so far figured out that it has to do something with the ahk_classes that I'm trying to address:

ahk_class GLFW30
ahk_class #32770

seem to be incompatible with my script, I don't understand why though.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the name of the program that you want it to work with so that we can better answer your question

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to get this to work with PokerStars.exe, I have now figured out that part of the problem is that the software uses ahk_class GLFW30 which seems to not be compatible with the script for whatever reason. Hope this helps?

Comment: Is the *only* goal to make a certain part of the software unclickable (i.e. do you care for whether or not that part of the screen is visible). If so, you could just use some if-logic with [MouseGetPos](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm) in order to determine what part of the screen the mouse is over, and if it is over a particular part of the screen, suppress mouse clicks.

Comment: Additionally, you can use [WinGetPos](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetPos.htm) to check the current size of the window, and with it, change the bounds of the screen that the MouseGetPos function mentioned above would suppress

Comment: Hey Spyre, thanks for your response. That does sound like a possible avenue, however I am a complete novice and not capable of writing/modifying anything else than I found online. And would the MouseGetPos even work with multiple and varying numbers of tables?